# Extracting query parameter value with POSIX regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, posix

Tinkering around with Google Analytics Advanced filters.

I know that if my Request URI is /?w=value1&x=value2&y=value3 and I want to extract the value of x, the regex would be x=([^&]*)

My question is WHY does that work?

Google support says the following:

[] = match one item in this list

^ = match to the beginning of the field

* = match zero or more of the previous item

How does that all come together to give me the value of query parameter x in x=([^&]*)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `^` in `[^&]*` actually means any character not in this list. The `^` character acts like a 'not' when it is in the brackets `[]` and beginning of the string when it is not in the brackets. So putting it all together, `x=([^&]*)` will get everything after `x=` then stop when it hits the next `&`.